What does 小さな裏切りさえ許せないほど求めて mean?
This line "小さな裏切りさえ許せないほど求めて" is from a song Hitotsu=Unmei Kyoudoutai by Can/Goo https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2KG-ISQmqf4  At 1:39, is the singer really saying "Even a small betrayal is easy to forgive" Is that translation correct? On google translate, it's getting translated as "I want it so much that I can't forgive even a small betrayal"  Could someone please tell me what is the correct translation?

The "easy to forget" translation is incorrect. I didn't listen to the song so I can't be 100% sure, but 求めて here probably means expectation from someone towards their love interest/romantic partner (hopefully a mutual one but this is unspecified).
I.e. they feel very strong romantic attraction to the point that they can't handle even the tiniest form of betrayal (like their partner going out with somebody else).
